# Sorting gets messed up

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I have implemented sorting with the help of this code. I am facing a problem. When the sort happens, the number 9 come before 15000. I don't know what to make of this. Please help!

```
NSSortDescriptor *lastDescriptor =
            [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
             initWithKey:@"priceAmount"
             ascending:NO];
id obj;
NSEnumerator * enumerator = [self.messageStore objectEnumerator];
while ((obj = [enumerator nextObject]))
    DebugLog(@"%@", obj);
NSMutableArray *descriptors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:lastDescriptor];
self.messageStore = (NSMutableArray *)[self.messageStore sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with selector `localizedStandardCompare`

```
NSSortDescriptor *lastDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"priceAmount" ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

Comment: is sortFlag a variable I'm supposed to create?

Comment: Any idea what to do when its with respect to date? I get jul before jun.

Comment: Only changes with respect to the first two numbers(day)

Comment: @sam24 you have to apply date comparison logic